# how to read a text file in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I am reading a txt file with a very simple code. The problem is that in the Log statments I only get the path of the file but contents are null. I guess that the problem lies in encoding part.Any Suggestions on how to read my text file.

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString* content;
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"colorpalette" ofType:@"txt"];
if(path)
{                                               
content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path  usedEncoding:&encoding  error:NULL];
}
NSLog(@"path is %@",path);
if (content)
{
    NSLog(@" content of file is %@",content);
}
```

Comment: How about reading the `error` provided by the method?

Comment: You could try using the error parameter to see what error is returned instead of passing it as NULL.

Comment: Joachim Isaksson I am getting the error " The opertion Couldn't be completed.

Answer (score 15):

Here encoding parameter is not set properly.

Try this

```
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@",path);
```

Comment: That is an option (arguably better if you know the encoding), however stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error: _is_ a perfectly valid overload if you don't know the encoding.

Comment: i figured out the mistake ..Actually at the time of saving the text file I selected the text encoding to Western(Mac OS Roman) ..it should be utf-8. now the code works perfect..:)

Comment: you mean " NSLog(@"%@",content); "  and not path

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code to read a Text File from Bundle :

```
NSError *error;
NSString *strFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
    pathForResource: @"FileName" ofType: @"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if(error) {  //Handle error

}

NSLog(@"File content : %@ ", strFileContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the encoding you are passing the function "stringWithContentsOfFile". Try passing it "NSUTF8StringEncoding". If this doesn't work, create an NSError instance and pass it by reference to the function.